# Некорректная формулировка уведомления: «... чаще одного раза»

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Надо бы переформулировать:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Заменить "чаще" на "более"?

Comment: @alexolut, там всё так просто?

Comment: А что там может быть сложно?

Comment: @alexolut, ну либо так кто-то почему-то перевёл, либо фразу опять из кусков составили ;)

Comment: @alexolut, запостил ответ тогда)

Comment: [Аналогично!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4853/176217)

Comment: Я в истории :) Явно видно что переводчик не знал контекста применения фразы.

Comment: @Other [переводчики](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhxWh.png)

Comment: @alexolut, спалились надмозги :)

Answer (score 2):

[Оригинальная строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262508?key=ff00bb075438be9a5693607f682de69d) выглядит так:

> You cannot mark a comment more than once

Как мне кажется, достаточно в текущем переводе заменить "чаще" на "более". Получим:

> Вы не можете отмечать комментарий более одного раза

Answer (score 2):

Зачем нам длинная фраза "более одного раза" или сложное слово "единожды"?

> Вы не можете отмечать комментарий дважды

Comment: А трижды, стало быть, могу?

Comment: Чтобы отметить что-либо трижды, нужно сначала отметить это дважды. А дважды вы не можете.

Comment: Не обязательно. Если повесить **сразу** три ярлыка - то это будет единомоментно. Без попадания в состояние "дважды". Другое дело, что в частном случае это действительно вряд ли возможно. Но с логической точки зрения `>1` надёжнее, чем `==2`.

Comment: Мы сейчас меняем только подсказку, а не логику работы. Мне кажется, что в подсказке слово "дважды" смотрится интуитивно понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Если эта фраза никак не строится из других, предлагаю такой перевод:

> Вы можете отметить комментарий лишь единожды.

Answer (score 0):

> Вы уже голосовали за этот комментарий

Comment: Мимо. Там не тревога, а обычный плюс был.

Comment: @Qwertiy, сообщение проявляется при лагах сети? Как можно увидеть его? Повторный клик предлагает снять плюс..

Comment: @vp_arth если вы быстро кликнете повторно, то да. А если подождёте, то увидите сообщение, которое мы обсуждаем.

Comment: Открываешь одно и то же в двух вкладках, ставишь комменту плюс, идёшь в соседнюю вкладку и ставишь плюс ещё раз. По идее, если снять плюс, то второй раз его поставить тоже нельзя - эту идею тоже надо проверить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, проверил, там будет "Вы уже отменили свой голос по данному комментарию; нельзя голосовать за него снова."